# Understanding Neo4j, creating unique nodes

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to wrap my head around how Neo4j works and how I can apply it to my problem. I thought it should be really easy and a matter of minutes, but I'm stuck.

I have data in MongoDB, say `User` and `Item`. What I want is connecting `User` and `Item` in a graph with a `LIKE` relationship (maybe with a `score`). Later I want to do things like recommending items based on connections, basic stuff.

But how do I get the data into Neo4j? Every document in MongoDB has an unique `_id`, so I though I could just throw both `_id`s into Neo4j and have them connected. What I found so far is that it's not even possible to have unique nodes based on the `_id` field (Neo4j has numeric incremented ids), which is only possible with some "hack" (https://github.com/jexp/app-net-graph/blob/master/lib/appnet.rb#L11) or using `MERGE` (I'm stuck on < 2.0). Even their examples on the website add the same node again if executed multiple times. I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to use Neo4j. Maybe I'm too spoiled by redis, where I can put strings in and and *it just works*. Redis' sets aren't feasible though for complex graphs, only for simple connections.

Maybe someone can help me with a simple cypher example of how to add two nodes `foo` and `bar` and have them connected with a `LIKE` connection. And the operation should be idempotent, no matter if none or all of the nodes/relationships already existed before execution.

I'm accessing Neo4j via REST, in particular using this node module https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j

Comment: too late but this might help you http://bit.ly/1qyCKnd

Answer (score 1):

You could define your external ID as extra property on your nodes. Then depending on if your are using SpringData or not, you can insert the data.

If you are using SpringData, you can configure your external ID as unique index and then normally save you nodes(consider though, that inserting a duplicated ID will overwrite the existing one).

If you are using the plain java API, you can create unique nodes as described here:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-unique-nodes.html#tutorials-java-embedded-unique-get-or-create

EDIT:
As for a sample query, does this help you?
http://console.neo4j.org/?id=b0z486

With the java api you would do it like this

```
firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
firstNode.setProperty( "externalID", "1" );
firstNode.setProperty( "name", "foo" );
secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
secondNode.setProperty( "externalID", "2" );
secondNode.setProperty( "name", "bar" );

relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.Likes );
```

I suggest you read some tutorials here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html

Comment: I updated my question. I'm not using Java, I need to use the REST api. In your example executing ` CREATE (_1 { name:"Foo" }),(_2 { name:"Bar" }), _1-[:LIKES]->_2` multiple times gives multiple independent node pairs.

Comment: Well of course, NEo4j  per default only enforces uniqueness on its internal IDs. If you are using REST and want to create unique nodes, maybe this is what you were looking for: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-unique-indexes.html

Comment: But this requires three roundtrips and takes the A out of ACID.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using Neo4J1.9, have you tried creating a unique index on your _ID column?

Try [this article](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.4/transactions-unique-nodes.html) from the docs

If you were using Neo4j2, then [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/neo4j-and-cypher-using-merge) is helpful

Comment: Wouldn't this again require multiple roundtrips? E.g. I create a unique `foo` node, then a unique `bar` node and then I connect them. But when connecting them, one or both may already have been deleted again. That's exactly what MERGE solves starting with v2.

Comment: You're using the REST interface? If so, try the Rest Batch interface as PhilBa suggests - you can create multiple nodes and relationships in a single call. Otherwise transaction management will give you ACID semantics

Comment: Won't the complete transaction fail if one of the calls fails because of the unique _id constraint? I'm currently not actively working on the Neo4j integration any more, so I'm thinking about deleting this question.